# IBOutlet not recognized in new target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, iboutlet

I have recently added a new target to my XCode swift iOS application project, all works fine apart from one UIViewController from the storyboard. When I reach it during the flow of my application, I get the following crash, which doesn't occur when running against the original target.

```
2017-01-08 11:47:22.714 SmoothCam Free[1179:269737] Unknown class _TtC6SmoothCam3PicReviewViewController in Interface Builder file.
2017-01-08 11:47:22.834 SmoothCam Free[1179:269737] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x1576f610> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key altitudeKey.'
```

I have checked that the class PicReviewViewController is building for both targets. In the main storyboard file, I have checked that the IBOutlet link for this "altitudeKey" Label is looking OK:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be causing this, and why I only get this problem with the new target?

Comment: Have you set the module for this new target?

Comment: I don't think so, what do you mean exactly? I have copied the target, changed the name, and pointed to a new Info.plist, and updated that accordingly

Comment: First check if you added this class to your target. If you did, something went wrong when you copied your target. Sometimes that can be caused because the app delegate's module was not set in IB under Custom Class.

Comment: Regards to @jvarela's comment: In IB, go to the Identity Inspector. Second dropdown is labelled "Module". You may choose from your targets there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was it. For this particular custom ViewController, in IB under the Custom Class in the identity inspector the first module was set. I blanked that and now it shows "Current Module - Module name" in grey and works for both targets. Thanks both!